# OSCommerce: How To Check If The Page Is "Product Page or Product Information"

Tags: oscommerce

In OSCommerce, how to check if the page is "Product Page or Product Information".

I mean if the page is in the product information, I want to put some condition only in product page, and this condition will not display in other pages in oscommerce.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
if(basename($PHP_SELF) == FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO){}
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is to use the product description - and locate it towards the bottom.